# Winhttp and p12 certificate

Tags: vb6, ssl-certificate, winhttp, winhttpcertcfg

I am writing a client program in VB6 which will interface to a server over HTTP.
The company who runs the server provided me with a certificate file called SomeCertificate.p12.

My program is running on Windows XP. This is the operating system the customer is using.

I am trying to find how to use this certificate when sending requests to the server.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Copied the certificate file to my test computer.
2. Using Internet Explorer V8, I did "Tools|Internet Options|Content|Certificates|Trusted Root Authorities" and imported the certificate.
3. Installed the winhttpcertcfg tool.
4. Ran the following from command prompt:

   "winhttpcertcfg -i SomeCertificate.p12 -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -a COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME -p PasswordFromServerCompany"

the output was something like this. I replaced the different tokens with dummy strings:

Imported certificate:

CN=string1

OU=string2

O=string3

L=string4

C=string5

Private key access has already been granted for account:
    COMPUTERNAME\USERNAME

6. My VB6 code looks something like this:

   Private WithEvents m_ServerObj As WinHttpRequest
   Set m_ServerObj = New WinHttpRequest
   m_ServerObj.Open "GET", "https://serveraddress"

   **Call m_ServerObj.SetClientCertificate("LOCAL_MACHINE\Personal\SomeCertificate")**

   m_ServerObj.Send TextToSend

The Send call causes an exception:
"A certificate is required to complete client authentication"

I tried different strings in the SetClientCertificate call but I keep getting the same error.

I'd appreciate any help and tips. What am i doing wrong? Is my code wrong? Did I use winhttpcertcfg  incorrectly?

thank you.

Comment: The fact i am using VB6 right now should not matter. The program is using Windows winhttp.dll, a COM object. I could have used C++ and still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The server company sent me a .PEM certificate to install. Once I did that, the problem was solved.
Thank you.